# MySQL ORDER BY WITH JOIN

Tags: mysql

Below is php code for a MySQL statement. I'm trying to order by lname which is a last name in the members table. I tried FROM members AS members1 and the inner AS members2 but this statement throws an error also. I believe the problem is I have two of the same column name but in the other ORDER BY JOIN examples I don't see this specific case where you have the same data column. The statement itself works fine as long as I don't comment in the last ORDER BY line.

```
$sql="
SELECT * 
  FROM members m
  JOIN paid p
    ON m.member_id = p.member_id 
 WHERE p.year = '$lastyear-12-31' 
   AND m.member_id NOT IN 
     ( SELECT x.member_id 
      FROM members x 
      JOIN paid y 
        ON x.member_id = y.member_id 
   WHERE y.year = '$thisyear-12-31') 
 ORDER 
      BY lname "
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: could be you have lname in both tables, paid and members. So you need to order by members.lname instead

Comment: Why do you have an `lname` field in the `paid` table? You shouldn't duplicate data across different tables.

Answer (score 0):

Name your columns. Add aliases to your column from where you want to order it.

```
$sql.="ORDER BY members.lname "
```

And you should be fine.